# Difficulty in compiling code on OSX terminal that works in Linux environment

Tags: c, linux, macos, terminal

I'm taking some working code (that I didn't write and the creator is not around anymore) to try and get it to compile on my Mac (10.9.5) using terminal.  I'm getting the following error when compiling (`gcc -o code code.c`):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   

    "_add_history", referenced from:
          _rl_gets in talk-c856c6.o   
    "_read_history", referenced from:
          _main in talk-c856c6.o   
    "_readline", referenced from:
          _rl_gets in talk-c856c6.o   
    "_write_history", referenced from:
          _rl_gets in talk-c856c6.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

here are all my includes:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <termios.h> 
#include <strings.h> 
#include <readline/readline.h> 
#include <readline/history.h>
```

I've found here and elsewhere online similar issues and have tried

```
#include <readline.h>
```

but get `fatal error: 'readline.h' file not found`
(same for `#include <libedit.dylib>`)

I'm a bit of a novice with external libraries so maybe I need to install another one?  Is my issue just that the mac needs an additional library installed to use those 5 functions creating errors, or are one of my #includes only for Linux and not for Mac?  I thought since both the Mac and the Linux are using Unix it would be the same, but apparently there are subtleties I don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gcc` only knows where to find a limited set of standard header files and libraries. You need the `-I` option to `gcc` to tell it where to find the readline header file(s), and the `-L` option for where to find the deadline libs (the search paths depend on where you installed readline). Also, `#include` cannot be used with .dylibs.

Comment: Interestingly if I try `gcc -o -I code code.c -ledit` I don't all the 4 individual symbol errors like in my original question/post, but I do get `ld: can't link with a main executable file 'talk' for architecture x86_64`

Comment: @BobbyDigital, `gcc -o -I code code.c -ledit` is broken.  The `-o` option must be followed by an output file name (of the desired executable, in this case), and the `-I` option must be followed by a path to a directory in which to search for include files.  My best guess is that omitting the `-I` will say what you actually mean to say.

Comment: thanks, all.  `gcc code.c -o code -l readline` also works.  the original error was misleading because this was actually an issue on the linux side too.  anyone have any resources to help me understand this library nuances better?

Comment: @BobbyDigital In C, including a header file merely makes the functions and variables declared in that header file known to your program. It does not cause the compiler to link in any library. You need to manually specify which libraries you want to link to. In this case, both `libedit` and `libreadline` supply the functions you want, so you can link against either, as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you bass the correct flags to the compiler? Seems like you are not linking against the `libedit`. Try passing `-ledit` to the compiler and tell us if that helps.

```
#include <libedit.dylib>
```

This is never correct. You can't `#include` a library, you need to tell the compiler that you want to link against this library when invoking it.

Comment: Wow, yes that worked! Thank you!  For the record I typed: `gcc -o code code.c -ledit`  The code is not working like I expected, though, but I will think about it some more to uderstand why and post.  Thanks again!